# Javascript Chart Library with zoom and large data support

Tags: javascript, charts, zooming

Would anyone recommend a particular JavaScript charting library with zoom functionality, supporting large size data around 2,50,000/250K plotting points at once.

open source would be recommended.

Comment: http://www.chartjs.org/ probably?

Answer (score 1):

My first thought would be either [d3.js](http://d3js.org) or [ZingChart](http://www.zingchart.com). d3 is open source, but the learning curve is pretty steep. ZingChart is closed, but much more approachable and provides support. Once you get into 50k+ points, other libraries tend to start having trouble.

Disclaimer: I'm on the ZC team. Feel free to reach out if you've got questions.

PPS. Next time you may want to post in [softwarerecs](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com). Be sure to read their post guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

Check the dyGraphs for this purpose. Have a look at the way it zooms:

http://dygraphs.com/tests/zoom.html